# Calculadora em javascript+ Html não Sai resultado

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Não sei o que fiz de errado, estou iniciando nisso e segui a apostila, mas da erro: alguem pode me ajudar?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculadora Basica</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function soma(){
            var numero1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n1').values);
            var numero2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n2').values);
            var resultado = numero1 + numero2;
            document.getElementById('result').value = resultado;
        }
        function subs(){
            var numero1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n1').values);
            var numero2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n2').values);
            var resultado = numero1 - numero2;
            document.getElementById('result').value = resultado;
        }
        function multi(){
            var numero1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n1').values);
            var numero2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n2').values);
            var resultado = numero1 * numero2;
            document.getElementById('result').value = resultado;
        }
        function divis(){
            var numero1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n1').values);
            var numero2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n2').values);
            var resultado = numero1 / numero2;
            document.getElementById('result').value = resultado;
        }

        window.onload = function(){
            alert("Calculadora. Seja Bem vindo - Teste de Alert");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
            <form>
                <div style="text-align:center; ">
                    Calculadora Basica
                    <br>
                    <input type="number" name="n1" id="n1">
                    <input type="button" value="+" onclick="soma();">
                    <input type="button" value="-" onclick="subs();">
                    <input type="button" value="x" onclick="multi();">
                    <input type="button" value="/" onclick="divis();">      
                    <input type="number" name="n2" id="n2">
                    =
                    <input type="number" name="resultado" id="result" >


                </div>
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Não sei o que pode ser, já faz 30min que já mudei o código e nada

Comment: Você esta pegando "values" o correto seria usar o método Value;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculadora Basica</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function soma(){
            var numero1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n1').value);
            var numero2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n2').value);
            var resultado = numero1 + numero2;
            document.getElementById('result').value = resultado;
        }
        function subs(){
            var numero1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n1').value);
            var numero2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n2').value);
            var resultado = numero1 - numero2;
            document.getElementById('result').value = resultado;
        }
        function multi(){
            var numero1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n1').value);
            var numero2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n2').value);
            var resultado = numero1 * numero2;
            document.getElementById('result').value = resultado;
        }
        function divis(){
            var numero1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n1').value);
            var numero2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n2').value);
            var resultado = numero1 / numero2;
            document.getElementById('result').value = resultado;
        }

        window.onload = function(){
            alert("Calculadora. Seja Bem vindo - Teste de Alert");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
            <form>
                <div style="text-align:center; ">
                    Calculadora Basica
                    <br>
                    <input type="number" name="n1" id="n1">
                    <input type="button" value="+" onclick="soma();">
                    <input type="button" value="-" onclick="subs();">
                    <input type="button" value="x" onclick="multi();">
                    <input type="button" value="/" onclick="divis();">      
                    <input type="number" name="n2" id="n2">
                    =
                    <input type="number" name="resultado" id="result" >


                </div>
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Foi necessário apenas tirar o **s** no fim de alguns dos **value**, veja se consegue agora.

Comment: Nossa não acredito que era isso, Valeu amigo hehe

Answer (score 2):

Cara, você apenas escreveu errado a propriedade **value**, você deixou como *values*.

O correto é assim:

```
var numero1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n1').value);
var numero2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n2').value);
```

Comment: Obg tb amigo....